# HTML - expand / collapse based on headings? "document map"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering what I would need to learn to do this in HTML pages instead of Microsoft Word Docs.

I use Word to create lengthy documents, and I use headings. Word has a built-in document map which exists as a "frame" to the left of the document. It reads any headings in the document and puts them as expandable and collapsible links in the left pane. This allows the user to easily navigate long documents by simply clicking the headings on the left pane.

Does anyone know if I can do this with HTML and CSS or do I need to learn JavaScript or something.?

I want to create a frame that AUTOMATICALLY gathers my headings and creates these links in a left frame just like in Microsoft Word but I want to do it in HTML pages.

If anyone knows and you could point me in the right direction on what I need to learn, I would appreciate it.

Word's Document Map
http://www.howtogeek.com/76818/learn-how-to-use-the-document-map-in-word-2007/

I want it to kind of look like this but auto generated in some way.
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction.html

Thanks,
mdwriter

Thanks for the comments below. It gives me a place to start.

Comment: Hi mdwrite, try to expand collapse using Jquery accordion. Here i added the tutorials for http://jqueryui.com/accordion/. Hope it should helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing... so i wrote some quick code to do something similar:

```
<html>
<header>
<style>
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}
#docmap {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; 
}
#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: 200px; 
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready( readyFn );

function readyFn( $ ) {
    var docmap = $("#docmap");
    var main   = $("#main");

    for(i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        main.append("<br>");
    }

    var all = main.find("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");
    docmap.append("<pre>");    
    iii = 1;
    all.each(function(){
      nextid = "link_" + iii;
      jQuery(this).attr("id", nextid);  
      var level = this.tagName.slice(1)
      var indent = ""
      for(i=0; i < level; i++) {
         indent += "*";
      }
      docmap.append("<a href=#" + nextid + ">" + indent +" " +  this.innerHTML + "</a><br>");
      iii++;
    });
    docmap.append("</pre>");    
}
</script>

</header>

<body>

<div id="docmap"></div>

<div id="main"><pre>

<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

'Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
The frumious Bandersnatch!'


<h2>Jabberwocky 2</h2>
He took his vorpal sword in hand:
Long time the manxome foe he sought --
So rested he by the Tumtum tree,
And stood a while in thought.

'Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
The frumious Bandersnatch!'

<h1>Jabberwocky 3</h1>

testing 456

<h2>A Strange Wild Song</h2>
A Strange Wild Song - Poem by Lewis Carroll

Autoplay next video
He thought he saw an Elephant
That practised on a fife:
He looked again, and found it was
A letter from his wife.
'At length I realize,' he said,
'The bitterness of life! '

He thought he saw a Buffalo
Upon the chimney-piece:
He looked again, and found it was
His Sister's Husband's Niece.
'Unless you leave this house,' he said,
'I'll send for the police! '

</pre></div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little jsfiddle that might get you started on the right track.

http://jsfiddle.net/h8Rcx/1/

Clicking on the list item looks for the associated h1 tag and then grabs that h1s sibling p text and puts it into another div.

You could do this directly with .sibling(), but I thought this might be easier to understand.

```
$('h1').each(function(idx,item){
   $('ul#list').append('<li class="'+$(this).attr('class')+'">'+item.innerText+'</li>');
});

$('li').on('click',function(){
    var selected_class=$(this).attr('class');
   $('#selected_content').html($('p.'+selected_class).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

File:toc.js

```
function readyFn( $ ) {
    var docmap = $("#docmap");
    var main   = $("#main");

    docmap.append("<a href='#main'>[top]</a>");

    /* delete leading whitespaces in main pre tag */
    var pre = document.querySelector("#main pre");
    pre.innerHTML = pre.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+/mg, "");

    for(i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        main.append("<br>");
    }

    var all = main.find("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");
    docmap.append("<pre>");    
    iii = 1;
        all.each(function(){
        nextid = "link_" + iii;
        jQuery(this).attr("id", nextid);    
        var slevel  = this.tagName.slice(1)
        var ilevel = parseInt(slevel)     

        var indent = ""
        for(i=0; i < ilevel-1; i++) {
           indent += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        docmap.append(indent + "<a href=#" + nextid + ">" +  this.innerHTML + "</a><br>");
    iii++;
    });
    docmap.append("</pre>");    
}

$( document ).ready( readyFn );
```

File:load.js

```
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../js/toc.css'>");
document.write("<script src='../js/jquery.min.js'></script>");
document.write("<script src='../js/toc.js'></script>");
```

FILE: example.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../js/load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="docmap"></div>

<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit above
<!----------------------------------------------->
<div id="main"><pre>

<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

<h2>Jabberwocky 1</h2>

'Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
The frumious Bandersnatch!'


<h3>Jabberwocky 2</h3>
He took his vorpal sword in hand:
Long time the manxome foe he sought --
So rested he by the <a href="google">Tumtum tree</a>,
And stood a while in thought.

'Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
The frumious Bandersnatch!'

<h2>Jabberwocky 3</h2>

testing 456

and plays the same role in discrete-time signal processing that the unit impulse plays in continuous-time signal processing. The unit sample may be used to decompose an arbitrary signal x(n) into a sum of weighted (scaled) and shifted unit samples as follows:

<h2>A Strange Wild Song</h2>
A Strange Wild Song - Poem by Lewis Carroll

Autoplay next video
He thought he saw an Elephant
That practised on a fife:

</pre></div>
<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit below
<!----------------------------------------------->
</body></html>
```

File: toc.js

```
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}

body {
  background-color: #2E3033  
}

a:link, a:visited {
   color: #FFFF00;
   color: skyblue;
   text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #505050;
   text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  background-color: hotpink;
   text-decoration: none;
} 

#docmap {

  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #B8BFC6;
  position: fixed;

  background-color: #2E3033  
}
#main {
  position: float;
  margin-left: 210px;
  position: 210px; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #363B40;
  color: #B8BFC6; 
}

h1{
    border: solid #ccc;
    color: #6699FF;
}

h2 {
   border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
   box-shadow: 0 3px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    #color: #FFCC00;
    color: #33FF99
}
```